# Unmount share on disconnect from SSH

Tags: bash, samba, cifs

I was able to get a windows share to mount when users ssh into our server in a sub-dir in `~`. I now want it so that when they disconnect, the mount unmounts. I added this to `/etc/bash.bashrc` but it doesn't seem to work.

```
finish() {
    sudo /usr/local/bin/disconnect_mount.sh
}

trap finish EXIT
```

In the shell script I have this:

```
if ["$PAM_TYPE" = "close_session" ]; then
        sudo umount ~/D
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created this script:

```
    #!/bin/sh

sudo umount ~/D
```

Then in /etc/bash.bashrc:

```
#Disconnect mount on session close
finish() {
 sudo /etc/bash.bash_logout
}
trap finish SIGHUP
```

And in /etc/sudoers:

```
ALL     ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/disconnect_mount.sh
```